# Collection or Array in my case?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have SQL request that returns (x,y,z) tuples with :

- x between 1 and 9
- y between 1 and 500
- z between 1 and 15

So I have 9 * 500 * 15 = 67500 possibilities maximum and 0 possibilities minimum if all my 67500 possibilities are stored into database.

I can have (4, 256, 1) for example in my lists but not (3, 410, 8).

I want to generate 3 linked lists. For example if I choose `x=2` I want the second list to display all the available y for this x value and idem for z values with y choice.

Should I use Collection ar Array to retrieve easily values to generate mys lists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the keys falling in small ranges like this, a simple 2D array of `short`s would be sufficient:

```
short data[10][500];
```

The first index is the value of `x`; the second index is the value of `y`.

The values of `z` are stored as individual bits of the `short` at `[x][y]`. To access individual bits, use bit operations:

```
if ((data[x][y] & (1 << z)) != 0) // The element at x,y,x is present
    ...
data[x][y] != (1 << z); // Add an element at x,y,z
data[x][y] &= ~(1 << z); // Remove the element at x,y,z
```

This data structure is very efficient in space: it needs roughly 10KBytes of memory to store the entire data set.

Comment: Hmm interesting but I didn't use bit operation yet, I don't understand it but I will read tutorials on this

Comment: @OlivierJ. Take a look at [this article](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=bitManipulation), it gives you a quick introduction to using bit operations "for fun and profit".

Answer (score 3):

I think it is always good to go with collections API when size of the data is not constant (or) known ahead of time.

You may use arrays and do `arrayCopy` if required, but it would be something re-inventing the cycle.

Comment: So I should use Set but which implementation is most suitable ?

Comment: In this case I think Maps are best than Set. If you would like to go with Sets, HashSet may be good option, refer this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/set.html

Answer (score 2):

In general, only use arrays when you absolutely have to (like not here).

You will find  `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

If your "list" of elements is constant you should use an array. With a query via JDBC API you will know how many rows the query will return.

Comment: It returns tuples (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), ..., (9, 500, 15) so I can't know directly number of distinct x, y,z

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I choose x=2 I want the second list to display all the
>   available y for this x value and idem for z values with y choice.

If you need fast retrieval may be you should look into a `Map`

Comment: Not exactly "instead of".  `Map<Integer,Map<Integer,List<Integer>>>`

Comment: I think so but is there another fast way ?